# Trying to update the progress bar

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

Basically, I want to update the Java `JProgressBar` as the function is run.

What is the syntax to do so?

Second, in doing so, does it need to complete the operation first to get the full amount of time? How can it know how long the task is if there is a chance that it varies based on input?

I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: What is the "java Swing Taskbar"?

Comment: Edited to Java Progress Bar

Comment: 1) The progress bar will not update if a long running task is blocking the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For a task of indeterminate length, use `JProgressBar.setIndeterminate(boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your question if you relate to a toolbar or to a progress bar.

See the documentation of class javax.swing.JToolBar for changing the toolbar.

But probably you would not want to update the toolbar itself but a JButton. You can change its properties at any time. Don't forget to call repaint() and possibly revalidate() as needed.

Normally for showing progress you would use a JProgressBar. See example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

Comment: Sorry about that -- edited.
I meant Progress Bar. 

I was able to update it from 0 to 100... but I'm not sure how to go about it for the entire function. Maybe a synchronized thread?